# How to compare 2 different records in the rsa archer?

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

Error should be displayed when 2 records have same name in the RSA archer? how to to compare 2 records in archer.

For example if the name of the record is xyz-draft.
and other record is xyz-draft

draft is the status of the record
then it should display the error

Comment: How is this problem related to [tag:rsa] (see the description: "RSA is a common public key algorithm, which can be used for encryption and signature")?

Comment: The OP is talking about RSA the security company, not RSA the algorithm. Until recently, RSA owned the Archer product. As of July 2023 it is now owned by Cinven.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make the "name" field require unique values?